# Safely add, subtract divide unsigned chars

Tags: c++, unsigned, integer-arithmetic

Say one has 8 unsigned chars `x1,x2,...x8` and we want to calculate:

```
abs((x1 + x2 + x3 + x4) - (x5 + x6 + x7 + x8)) / 4
```

What would be the best way to ensure the most accurate results, without introducing large overflow or underflow errors?

I'm using this in a template class, which is why I cannot just convert the unsigned values to signed ones.

Comment: Safe averaging of two numbers was done [here](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html), but this is a bit more complex :(

Comment: Whats about casting them to ints before and casting the result back to char after?

Comment: Casting the values to `int` would make the most sense. Think of what would happen if the sum of `x5..x8` is greater than the sum of `x1..x4`. Besides, `abs()` expects a signed `int` anyway, so do your calculations using signed `int` values.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - as I mentioned, this is a template class, and can take on floats or signed ints. The worst case is with unsigned chars, hence the question.

Comment: Why don't you write a specialization for `unsigned` that casts to `int` then? :v

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `operator +` only works for `int` and larger. Thus when you use it with objects of type `char` (which is smaller than int) these values are automatically converted to int before the operation happens.

Thus

```
abs((x1 + x2 + x3 + x4) - (x5 + x6 + x7 + x8)) / 4
```

Is converted by the compiler to:

```
abs((static_cast<int>(x1) + static_cast<int>(x2) + static_cast<int>(x3) + static_cast<int>(x4)) - 
    (static_cast<int>(x5) + static_cast<int>(x6) + static_cast<int>(x7) + static_cast<int>(x8))) / 4
```

So unless you are adding up a lot of char you are unlikely to overflow.

There is an issue assigning the result back to `unsigned char`. If result of the expression is negative then you are going to have a conversion that makes the value positive (but well defined).

Comment: Key phrases: "usual arithmetic conversions" [expr]/10, "integral promotion" [conv.prom]

Comment: If you have compiler warnings cranked up and assign the result back to an `unsigned char`, you'll get a truncation warning. This is why.

Comment: Conversion from a negative value to an unsigned type is not UB nor undefined value, it uses 2's complement [conv.integral]/2. And it's probably easier to test if it *has overflowed* than to test *if it will overflow*.

Comment: @DyP: You are correct I will update. But the standard does not specify 2's compliment. That kind of limiting of the language would never be allowed. It does note that the specified conversion would not cause a change in bit pattern for 2's complement (as this is the most common representation).

Comment: Yes, I was abbreviating a bit. What I meant was *the behaviour here is as if the negative value was represented as 2's complement and you'd just reinterpret the bits*.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want a metafunction to tell you what intermediate data type to use in your calculations.

```
    template <class T>
    struct arithmetic_type
    {
        typedef std::int64_t type;
    };

    template <>
    struct arithmetic_type<float>
    {
         typedef double type;
    };

    template <>
    struct arithmetic_type<double>
    {
         typedef double type;
    };

    template <>
    struct arithmetic_type<std::uint64_t>
    {
         typedef std::uint64_t type;
    };

    typedef typename arithmetic_type<T>::type ar_type;
    abs(((ar_type)x1 + x2 + x3 + x4) - ((ar_type)x5 + x6 + x7 + x8)) / 4;
```

You can of course tweak the specializations and add/remove as per your needs, but this should give you the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

As with any fixed-size data, the best approach is to cast them to a type large enough to fit the worst case scenario. In this case, casting them to `int` will be good enough - it will fit range of any possible values and will allow handling potential underflow.

Note that you will have to be careful about subtraction - the result will depend on the semantics you want to attach to it: either you assume that it will never underflow (and any negative value is an error or should be floored at 0) or negative value has a meaning and you do want to take an absolute value out of it.

Comment: No need to cast. All operations are automatically done on int. This is the smallest size operations are done on. So the above code should work as expected all the time.